# Can I use Firefox Dev tools in a seperate button on the task bar?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, browser, firefox-developer-tools

I'm on Windows 10 and am using Firefox Developer Edition. In Chrome, if I open the Dev Tools, I can undock the Dev Tools into a separate window. This creates a new task bar button specifically for the Dev Tools window.

[image]

When I undock the Dev Tools into a separate window in FF however, the Dev Tools window is layered under the FF web view window.

[image]

Windows 10 settings allows to have all task bar buttons unlayered and without labels, but this looks pretty messy.

Is there any way to get FF to behave the way Chrome does when the Dev Tools are opened in a separate window? I've looked in the setting for the Dev Tools but don't see any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

When Windows is set to combine taskbar buttons together (as it does by default), it'll always group windows together from the same program (executable) unless the program itself specifically tells Windows not to.

In the case of Chrome and Chromium, I know it is programmed in such a way that loading multiple profiles causes the taskbar icons for each profile to be split up, and I assume dev tools achieves the same thing.

Firefox sadly doesn't do this (I previously put in a feature request ticket for this, but it's probably stagnated since then). The only way to have them as separate taskbar items is to change your taskbar settings to 'never combine'.

Comment: That's a bummer. This confirms what I've found as well. There are plenty of taskbar items I do want to combine, but not the Firefox inspector. Thanks for the answer and putting in a ticket!

Comment: This is now a few years old but could someone link to the feature request?

Comment: Sorry... Couldn't find it on Bugzilla.